# pgRouting Front End/API

Tags: web-services, api, postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I can't find any reliable info about some kind of "human" readable front end or api to pgRouting.

I have OSM PostGIS/pgRouting database which I would like to use to calculate paths between points. The problem is that I can't find any software that would use pgRouting to expose some ind of API. (WebService/comandline/anything usable)

I would like to provide to such API start, endpoint (GPS cords) and some parameters (don't use high ways and such). As a result I'm counting for distance, travel time and list of points to draw a poly on map.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As I know, there isn't any apps, that you looking for, so you have to operate with direct SQL commands. (pgRouting is just a collection of functions in postgreSQL).

Comment: I know that. QGIS can use them, but I'm searching for some kind of web xml/json based frontend

Answer (score 0):

> A simple pgRouting direction back-end API written in javascript nodejs express.

Easy to use and deploy.

https://github.com/imran-5/pgRouting-Direction-API